# @Before is not getting executed when @RunWith(DataProvider.class)

Tags: java, selenium, junit, apache-poi

I have a Test Case Class. But @Before is not getting called.
How to call @Beofre first and call @RunWith ?

```
@RunWith(DataProviderRunner.class)
public class Ab extends xyz {

    @DataProvider
    public static Object[][] workBookSheet()
    {
        Object[][] tableArray = ex.getTableArray("Ab");
        return (tableArray);
    }

    @Test
    @UseDataProvider("workBookSheet")
    public void Abc(String TestName, String sDescription)
    {
         }
```

xyz class has below code and also @Before annotation.

```
protected static ExcelSheet ex;
    static {
        try {
            String Path = getPath();
            ex = new ExcelSheet("sheet.xlsx");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

@Before
{
public static String getPath()
{
}
}
```

Or is there a way in Junit to use DataProvider with RunWith and invoke @Before first. Or is there a way to create a custom annotation and add these with @RunWith ?

Answer (score 1):

Static methods do not take part in polymorphism

```
@Before
public String getPath() {
```

Comment: No if you see the structure Test has static methods too. Before irrespective of static or non static RunWith is launcing first.